# Internationalization with Seam 2.2.2

Tags: internationalization, seam, facelets, bundle

I have a jboss seam 2.2.2 project and it is my first time using internationalization with this framework. I have already set the default locale and using the global messages_XX.properties is already working. 
Well, this project is growing fast and for better organization and for ease of maintance I would like to have the messages better organized in various properties files for specific pages. 
[Seam documentation on internationalization](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/i18n.html) mention this and in a specific paragraph it says:

> If you want to define a message just for a particular page, you can
>   specify it in a resource bundle with the same name as the JSF view id,
>   with the leading / and trailing file extension removed. So we could
>   put our message in welcome/hello_en.properties if we only needed to
>   display the message on /welcome/hello.jsp

This paragraph can be found at: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/i18n.html#d0e14166

The docs mention pages with .jsp extension but in my case I am using facelets and what I have is a .xhtml file so for my home.xhtml page I have created a home_pt_BR.properties file being pt_BR the default locale for my app and I have placed messages for this specific page in this .properties file.

Actually this approach did not work for me.

I have also tryed to register the page in faces-config.xml and also in pages.xml but again this does not seem to work.

So, how do I configure Seam to support multiple bundle files for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the bundle files to components.xml

For example:

```
<core:resource-loader>
    <core:bundle-names>
        <value>messages</value>
        <value>strings</value>
    </core:bundle-names>
</core:resource-loader>
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what did you suggested but I will take a look on this option. Could you be more specific? Where do I declare the bundle name? Is one bundle name for each value tag?

Comment: Hi, I took a look at the suggested aproach and in fact it does not satisfy my requirenments as it would be proibitive and a maintance-hell to keep track of all the bundle files in the system in the conponents.xml file. I would like to make the approach of keeping one bundle file for each file per language like seam doc suggest should work.

Comment: Actually your solution does not satisfy my requirements but as far as it looks like the only solution I will consider it correct. I still believe that there is some other simpler way of doing this or maybe I just missunderstood seam documentation on that.